# Active State Perl : Unable to download modules using ppm

Tags: perl, installation, module

I have downloaded active state perl on a windows 32 bit machine. I have perl file which uses CGI Lite module. So I tried installing it from the command prompt. But its giving me an error. How can I download the desired modules in active state perl using the ppm?

```
P:\>ppm install CGI-Lite
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides CGI-Lite
```

[image]

Comment: `ppm search CGI` to find it first?

Comment: `P:\>ppm search CGI
*** no packages matching 'CGI' found ***`

Comment: did you try gui? http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_gui

Comment: What's version of Perl?

Comment: Perl version - Perl 5.16.3

Comment: I have added a screen shot of my ppm. I saw a message `Downloading Repository ..not found` so its not synchronized? And the total list of packages were shown as `273 Packages` only. Is that the total list of packages?

Comment: Could have mentioned that sooner....

Comment: If you go trough menus Edit | Preferences | Repositories, do you see "ActiveState Package Repository"? If so, could you provide the value you see in the "URL" field?

Comment: `http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.16/1603/package.xml`

Comment: (273 is the number of packages found locally)

Comment: Just upgraded to 5.16.3 and got the module from that same repo no problem. Not a problem with the repo. Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: I am using ppm thru a proxy..I have set the http_Proxy in my system env variables as well

Comment: Sounds like a problem getting ppm to use the proxy or getting the proxy to work. I know nothing about either. (Another detail that would have been useful to know much earlier.)

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution from the following document:

http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/using-ppm-thru-proxy

Answer (score 1):

By the way the ActiveState's Perl contain `cpan` utility allowing you to install modules which have no versions in the Repositories. Just type in `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\users\roman> cpan CGI::Lite
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working under a proxy, run these commands from command prompt:

```
SET HTTP_proxy=http://proxy:port      #for this check your proxy setting
SET HTTP_proxy_user=<your user name>  #system user
SET HTTP_proxy_pass=<your password>   #password for same user
```

Read this [document](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.6/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_and_proxies) for details.